# increase speed in magento 1.7

Tags: magento

My site installed in magento 1.7, runs slow on server after installation but it is ok in my local.I have disabled catch and rerun the site and then enabled it but it still remains the same.Has it to do with hosting?Is there any easy way to speed up magento after installation in server using php.ini or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase speed you can use .htaccess for this purpose :
Just in your .htaccess file  for Magento (located in the root) you will find a section of text starting with the line `<IfModule mod_deflate.c>` and ending at `</IfModule>`

Refer to this [link](http://magentobingo.blogspot.in/) for more information.

Comment: Your link just points to a site. Please use a specific one.

Answer (score 2):

**Tips for Magento site speed up**

1. Enable all Magento caching layers.
2. Configure your web server to enable Connection Keep-Alive, enable
   mod_expire, gzip compression
3. Enable MySQL Query caching.
4. Install APC or XCache to cache PHP opcode.
5. Install Memcache and configure Magento to store session and cache to
   memory.
6. Install third-party Full Page Cache Magento extension.
7. Install Varnish cache server for full page caching on system layer.

Ref: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/36225/

Answer (score 1):

*Tips for increase speed in magento*

```
- Uninstall any extensions that you don’t actually use.
 - Disable modules that you don’t use from: System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Advanced.
 - Enable all Magento Caches: System -> Cache Management.
 - Combine Javascript and Combine CSS files: System ->Configuration ->Advanced ->Developer -> ‘Javascript settings’ and ‘CSS Settings’.
 - Try some of the Magento performance extensions.
 - Enable the Magento Flat Catalog, only helpful for very large catalogs to feel the improvements.
 - Don’t use layered navigation if you don’t really need it, it’s resource intensive.
 -  turn on Magento’s Compilation feature. 
 - Set only those attribute frontend properties to ‘Yes’ that you’re actually going to use
 - Disable the Magento log: System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Log Settings 
 - Use magento speed up extension lots of extension are free
```

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20140327173649/http://www.gxjansen.com/101-ways-to-speed-up-your-magento-e-commerce-website/